# My breaker keeps tripping

Tags: electric-motor

Help ,My motorized garage door opener is tripping my breaker when I use it , can I install a higher amp breaker ?

Comment: May we have more information, please?  Like the make/model of the opener, and whether it is on a shared circuit, and how old is the breaker and what is its rated amperage?  With that information in hand, I would think you will get answers to this question.

Comment: The garage door opener motor and the breaker should both have plaques or labels with electrical data on them (current, voltage, frequency, fuse trip data, etc.). Please [edit] your question to include the information from those to the best of your ability. Also as SDsolar said, tell us what you know about the age of the breaker (they do wear out eventually) and whether (and what) anything else is connected to the same circuit breaker.

Comment: A circuit breaker should *never* trip under normal use; if it does, especially repeatedly, assume a problem *somewhere*. ***DO NOT*** simply install a higher amperage breaker to "fix" this -- *figure out what the real problem is and address that first.* If you aren't comfortable working with high voltage electricity, **call a professional.** High-voltage electrical circuits is one of the few areas where you literally might not get a second chance to get it right, due to everything from a house fire to your own death; keep this in mind before deciding whether this is a DIY kind of job.

Comment: To translate a little, your question is really "My breaker is annoying me by doing its intended job! How do I stop it and make my home unsafe?" ... Do you see the problem here?

Comment: The breaker is there to protect the wiring. If it's tripping because the motor is drawing too much current, changing the breaker may cause the wiring to overheat (and catch fire). That's why, at a minimum, the question needs the breaker rating and the motor rating. But assessing the cable and its current-carrying capacity will need a site visit from an electrician.

Comment: If the breaker is a ground fault type (GFCI) it may be bad. GFCI breakers are known to have problems with motor loads. As others have mentioned don't increase the size if a GFCI replace it with the same size and type.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling  Ha!  In my youth (you young whippersnappers) the approach was to replace a screw-in fuse with a penny.  You could run a hundred amps or so thru that :-)

Comment: In nearly all cases of "<X> fault protection breaker keeps tripping, why on earth does this happen?" the answer is almost always "Something has <X> fault, and it's the thing you suspect.  Fix that."

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is check out the door.  Unplug the motor and pull the disconnect cord to separate the door from the drive mech.  Now manually try opening and closing the door.  If it doesn't move smoothly (or worse, you just now notice a broken spring or cable), then fix the mechanicals.
Only after that should you start suspecting a bad breaker, and as EdBeal commented, never increase the rating.